# How to hide text fields and value when input fields is null

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

I need to hide a field on page load based on the value of a request attribute. I don't want a 'hidden' field because I want to show it again. I don't want to do this with javascript,ajax. How is this done with jsp tags? I have this code, when i run this code my text value has been hide(ie 56785456577) but am not able to hide the text fields(ie Tel No)...I have this code

```
 <s:if test="purchaseOrder.company.phone!=''">

 <div id="phone_no" class="draggable ui-widget-content resizeable"
 <s:set var="phone_no"
 value="#formSetupTemplate.formSetupTemplateElementList.
 {^#this.drag_id=='phone_no'}"/>

 <s:if test="#phone_no!=null && #phone_no.size!=0">

 <s:set var="phone_no" value="#phone_no[0]"/>

 style="position: <s:property value="#phone_no.position"/>; top:

 <s:property value="#phone_no.top"/>;

 left:<s:property value="#phone_no.left"/>; width: 

 <s:property value="#phone_no.width"/>;
 height: <s:property value="#phone_no.height"/>;

 </s:if>">
 <p>Tel.No: <s:property value="company.phone"/></p>

 </div>

 </s:if>">
```

Through the above code am able to hide text filed value(ie phone no- 56785456577) but am not able to hide text fields name  ie Tel No(Fields Name)Here am also attaching the image [In the Given Image Am unable to hide Tel No](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtIF2.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

JSP 2.0 Expression language(EL) can rescue here. Below is small snippet that can help,

```
<html><head><title>Simple Example</title></head><body><p><b>$fFieldName}<b>,<br/>${fieldValue}</p></body></html>
```

for this you need to do changes in your `Servlet` or `POJO` like if fieldValue is present then set fieldName also. if in case you see EL name on your page then set `isElIgnored` page attribute to `false`